# C difference between (!pointer) and (pointer != NULL),

Tags: c, pointers

I'm currently learning how to code C and stumbled upon an interesting line,

Apparently,

```
struct node{
    node *next;
};

node *head = (node *)calloc(1, sizeOf(node));
head->next = NULL;

node *currentNode = head;
while (!currentNode)
```

In this context, is

```
while(!currentNode)
```

different to

```
while(currentNode != NULL)
```

? I thought they meant to check for the same stuff, when current Node is not NULL but they are returning different results and I dont' understand...

Comment: While learning C I suggest you configure your compiler to give errors when presented with invalid code. The code above is invalid C (I suspect it is valid C++) as there is no type named `Node` defined.

Comment: `while(!currentNode)` is exactly the opposite of `while(currentNode != NULL)`.

Comment: @pmg: it is invalid C++, too, IMHO. (there is a semicolon missing after the struct definition)

Comment: @wildplasser apart from semicolon, what exactlly makes it invalid **C**?

Comment: @REACHUS: the snippet above does not define a type named `Node` yet it uses that type name in a few statements.

Comment: @REACHUS : in C, a struct definition is not a typedef. `Node *head = ...` is invalid in C, and should be `struct Node *head = ...` .Also: tthe struct definition `struct Node node{
    Node *next;
}` is completetly wrong, even with a semicolon appended.

Comment: invalid C : the type of variables, members etc is `struct node`, not `node` alone.

Comment: latest edit is even worse. please check your code compiles before posting

Comment: Compile C code with a C compiler; compile C++ code with a C++ compiler. Don't mix the languages (or compilers).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how is that relevant

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah, one is the boolean opposite of the other  , it is unrelated as to whether NULL is all-bits-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(currentNode)
```

and

```
while(currentNode != NULL)
```

are equivalent.

The first says that while `currentNode` has some value (could be anything, even garbage), the second one says that while `currentNode` is not `NULL`, i.e., has some value.

On the other hand,

```
while(!currentNode)
```

means that while `currentNode` does not hold any value, i.e, is `NULL`.